# Call a Jquery Function after Another Jquery in ASP.Net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have two JQuery functions both working for Gridview in ASP.Net

**1. Function to Fixate Gridview Header and create Auto Scrollbars**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery/JQueryUICalendar/js/gridviewScroll.min.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var $160 = jQuery.noConflict();
    $160(document).ready(function () {
        gridviewScroll();
    });

    function gridviewScroll() {
        $160('#<%=grdTenant.ClientID%>').gridviewScroll({
            width: 1080,
            height: 340,
          // freezesize: 2, //kung gusto mag free yung column enable this pls
            //IsInUpdatePanel: true
           arrowsize: 30,
           varrowtopimg: "images/arrowvt.png",
           varrowbottomimg: "images/arrowvb.png",
           harrowleftimg: "images/arrowhl.png",
           harrowrightimg: "images/arrowhr.png"
        });
    }

</script>
```

**2. Function to auto filter a record in gridview using keypress event in textbox.**

```
 var $KeyPressSearch = jQuery.noConflict();
function filter2(phrase, _id) {

var words = phrase.value.toLowerCase().split(" ");
var table = document.getElementById(_id);

var ele;
for (var r = 1; r < table.rows.length; r++) {
ele = table.rows[r].innerHTML.replace(/<[^>]+>/g, "");
var displayStyle = 'none';
for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
if (ele.toLowerCase().indexOf(words[i]) >= 0)
displayStyle = '';
else {
displayStyle = 'none';
break;
}
}
table.rows[r].style.display = displayStyle;

}
```

and in input textbox

```
  <input id="txtTerm" name="txtTerm" onkeyup="filter2(this, '<%=grdTenant.ClientID %>')" type="text"   size="40"  />
```

**Problem:**

Everytime I use the textbox for searching, upon keypress, the records are being filtered but the format of the gridview itself is becoming **disorganized and misaligned**. ***Please see image below***

> [image]

**Solution:**

What I tried to do is re-apply the first function everytime the second function (keypress searching) is executing.

```
 <input id="txtTerm" name="txtTerm" onkeyup="filter2(this, '<%=grdTenant.ClientID %>')" type="text"   size="40" onclick="gridviewScroll()" />
```

What I did is include an ***onclick attribute to the input text and call the gridviewscroll function***, but still it does not work successfully. other options are:

1. Maybe it should be on keypress event again instead of onclick?
2. or include the code directly in the jquery function and make them one?

Badly needed your expert advice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: try putting `gridviewScroll()` at the last line of `filter2` ?

Comment: Ok, I will. Why down vote?

Comment: hi @BenG i TRIED it has  improved a bit, but still the columns are misaligned.

Answer (score 0):

GOT THE ANSWER.

I joined two javascript functions. First I put the first Javascript code into a function and call it in the second. See codes

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery/JQueryUICalendar/js/gridviewScroll.min.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">

    function callGridviewScroll() {
        var $160 = jQuery.noConflict();
        $160(document).ready(function () {
            gridviewScroll();
        });

        function gridviewScroll() {
            $160('#<%=grdTenant.ClientID%>').gridviewScroll({
                width: 1080,
                height: 340,
                // freezesize: 2, //kung gusto mag free yung column enable this pls
                //IsInUpdatePanel: true
                arrowsize: 30,
                varrowtopimg: "images/arrowvt.png",
                varrowbottomimg: "images/arrowvb.png",
                harrowleftimg: "images/arrowhl.png",
                harrowrightimg: "images/arrowhr.png"
            });
        }


</script>


      <script type="text/javascript">
          var $KeyPressSearch = jQuery.noConflict();
          function filter2(phrase, _id) {

              var words = phrase.value.toLowerCase().split(" ");
              var table = document.getElementById(_id);

              var ele;
              for (var r = 1; r < table.rows.length; r++) {
                  ele = table.rows[r].innerHTML.replace(/<[^>]+>/g, "");
                  var displayStyle = 'none';
                  for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
                      if (ele.toLowerCase().indexOf(words[i]) >= 0)
                          displayStyle = '';
                      else {
                          displayStyle = 'none';
                          break;
                          callGridviewScroll();

                      }

                  }
                  table.rows[r].style.display = displayStyle;

              }

              var lblTotalDSRdata = $KeyPressSearch("#grd tr").length;

          }




</script>
```

So, Fixing a gridview header while performing an auto-filter searching of records in it without realigning or misaligning the columns and over-all format is solved. Hope it could help others too.